# How can I fill the category field in a raster using GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have a tiff file with land use data. The land use class in in the value field, but the label field is empty. 
Now I want to find out which is the area covered by each land use class, but GRASS does not find any category data.

So I wanted to copy the data in the value field to the category field, but I have not yet found any way of doing this.

Comment: I would be interested in how to use r.category. Let's say i have raster labels 1 and 2 and i would like to assign them:
1:Trees
2:Pasture How can i do that with r.category? i tried the following:
r.category map rules=- but then i don't know how to assign the new values within the console...
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[r.category](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.category.html) should give you all the flexibility you need to manage category values and labels